# What are the differences between "for (auto&& i : v) " and "for (auto& i : v) "? Are there some portential problems when using "for (auto&& i : v)"?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

What are the differences between `for (auto&& i : v)` and `for (auto& i : v)`?

I understand that `auto&&` is a universal reference. I clearly know `auto &&` could return references of rvalues and lvalues. Does `auto &` only return a reference of lvalues. Am I right? Are there some potential problems with `for (auto& i : v)`?

Here is some related code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (auto& i : v) 
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << typeid(i).name() << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto&& i : v) 
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << typeid(i).name() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think the suggested page answers this question.At least, for the question,"Does auto & only return a reference of lvalues?"

Comment: `auto&` cannot bind to rvalues. If the container's iterator returns rvalues rather than lvalues, the code will not compile.

Comment: @Raymond Chen  How can I confirm which kind of reference it returns, e.g. vector<bool>, vector<int>(their return types diff)?

Comment: You have to consult the documentation. For example, `vector<T>`'s `reference` is a `T&`. Whereas `vector<bool>'s is a separate class (a proxy).

Comment: @Raymond Chen  What does "proxy" mean? Is it a terminology?

Comment: [Proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

Comment: @RaymondChen Quote:"vector<T>'s reference is a T&. Whereas `vector<bool>'s is a separate class (a proxy). "  If I correctly understand you, `vector<bool>` does not have any relationship with `vector<T>`. Am I right?

Comment: [`vector<bool>` is a specialization of `vector<T>`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.bool).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank  you for the clarification.